# Access articles in Joomla 3.9 from external php file, blank page?

Tags: php, joomla

I try to access to article by `ID` (let say id 179), but in my Joomla 3.9.3 site, it show a blank page and nothing happen. 
Here is my code (name `get.php`, it's on same root folder with `configuration.php`, `index.php`, `robots.txt` ...)

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    define('_JEXEC', 1);
    define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php' );
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('');
    var_dump($app);
    $app->initialise();
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();// Joomla database object
    $sql = "SELECT fulltext FROM #_content WHERE id = 179";
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $fullArticle = $db->loadResult();
    if(!strlen(trim($fullArticle))) $fullArticle = "Article is empty ";
    echo $fullArticle;
  ?>
```

Even nothing show when I `var_dump()`;

What did i do wrong or Joomla 3.9.3 change the way we access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code -

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.legacy.php';
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
// var_dump($app);
// $app->initialise();
$db = JFactory::getDBO();// Joomla database object
$sql = "SELECT `fulltext` FROM #__content WHERE id = 179";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$fullArticle = $db->loadResult();
if(!strlen(trim($fullArticle))) $fullArticle = "Article is empty ";
echo $fullArticle;
```